# ColorBars or PlotLegends for ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D

Tags: differential-equations, graphics3d, finite-element-method

I want to produce a colorbar legend to the output from ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D (Mathematica 10). The pde was solved using NDSolveValue (FEM pdesolution is the resulting interpolating function) over a 3d mesh called emesh and plotted using:

```
ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D[pdesolution, Boxed -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Seems to me PlotLegends and ColorBars are not applicable to ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D. At least I cannot get them to work. Suggestions how to display a color bar?

I thought of doing it separately by first trying to determine the maximum and minimum values of the interpolating function solution over emesh but I am unsure how to apply FindMaxValue and FindMinValue to this problem. It seems a rather unnecessary approach though. Surely there is a more elegant way that is perhaps just not well documented in Wolfram's 3D FEM Info.

In case it is useful here is how I got pdesolution

```
pdesolution = NDSolveValue[(-σ)*Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]  == 
NeumannValue[hcoeff*(Tair - u[x, y, z]), 
  ElementMarker == 2 && z != 0] + 
 NeumannValue[Heatdensity1, 
  z == 0 && (Qs[[3]][[1]] ⩽ x ⩽ Qs[[4]][[1]]) &&
       (Qs[[5]][[1]] ⩽ y ⩽ Qs[[6]][[1]])] + 
 NeumannValue[Heatdensity2, 
  z == 0 && (Qs[[3]][[2]] ⩽ x ⩽ Qs[[4]][[2]]) && 
       (Qs[[5]][[2]] ⩽ y ⩽ Qs[[6]][[2]])] + 
 NeumannValue[Heatdensity3, 
  z == 0 && (Qs[[3]][[3]] ⩽ x ⩽ Qs[[4]][[3]]) && 
       (Qs[[5]][[3]] ⩽ y ⩽ Qs[[6]][[3]])] + 
 NeumannValue[Heatdensity4, 
  z == 0 && (Qs[[3]][[4]] ⩽ x ⩽ Qs[[4]][[4]]) && 
       (Qs[[5]][[4]] ⩽ y ⩽ Qs[[6]][[4]])], 
 u, {x, y, z} ∈ emesh];
```

With Thanks

Comment: To get the `MinMax` you could use `{min,max}=MinMax[pdesolution["ValuesOnGrid"]];`

Answer (score 4):

Since the mesh for the picture in the OP was not provided, I'll use [this example from an FEM tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#870387680), but with altered boundary conditions:

```
bcs = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd,
  {{DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == 2, ElementMarker == 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == 0, ElementMarker == 2]}}]
```

Using the corresponding interpolating function `eufun`, we can do this:

```
With[{vals = eufun["ValuesOnGrid"]},
 Legended[
  ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D[vals, eufun["ElementMesh"], Boxed -> False],
  BarLegend[{ColorFunction /. Options[ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D] // First, MinMax@vals}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the use of `MinMax` was mentioned by [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114439/colorbars-or-plotlegends-for-elementmeshsurfaceplot3d/120382#comment310443_114439).